# Python Inventory Dictionary Text Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Anaconda 3 > Python 3 > Spyder 3. I am currently working on a text based survival game. I am using a dictionary for my inventory. I have figured out how to add and remove items from my inventory, but I have some `def blablabla():` used in my game market for buying and selling items. The problem is, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use `def blablabla():` for my market. Most importantly though, when in the `def BuyThisStuff():` I use a line of code that is supposed to check if I have enough currency to purchase that thing. That is where I get an error saying:`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` here is my inventory code:

```
inventory = {'coins':'750',
"Loaf of Bread": "2",
"Bottle of Water": "3",}
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = (inventory.values())
    item_total = sum(map(int, item_total))
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v + '   ' + k)
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))
displayInventory(inventory)
```

To add an item to my inventory I use:

```
inventory['Rock'] = '3'
```

To remove:

```
del inventory['Rock']
```

Here is the error code:

```
def MarketBuyFishingRod ():
    global coins
    if inventory['coins':] > 299:
        inventory['coins'] = inventory['coins'] - 300
        print ("You have bought a fishing rod for 300 coins!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("Now in your inventory you have:")
        #inventory = inventory + ["Loaf of Bread", ]
        inventory['Fishing Rod'] = '1'
        print (inventory)
        InvFishingRod = True
     else:
        print ("You need to have at least 300 coins to buy a Fishing Rod!")
```

(Error is in line 3)

```
if inventory['coins':] > 299:
```

As shown in the inventory code, you start with 750 coins. Now I need     `def MarketBuyFishingRod ():` to check if the player has over 299 coins in their inventory. Unfortunately this raises an error I do not know how to fix. Please Reply and help me, I would really appreciate your help.
If you need any extra info reply and I will answer.

Comment: You should really read about [mre]. All this story and code are not relevant to solve a simple `TypeError`... Anyways, what's not clear with the error? The values of `inventory` are strings (`'750'`, `'2'` etc.) and `299` is an int. Either do `int(inventory["coins"])` or simply save the values as ints: `inventory = {"coins": 750}`

Comment: Getting the `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`error. Changing inventory strings intergals didn't help: `int(inventory = {'coins':'750',})`. Goal: `def FishingRod():` to check in inventory, if the player has more than 299 'coins'. Here is my full code: `inventory = {'coins':'750',}
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print (inventory)
displayInventory(inventory)
def FishingRod ():
    if inventory["coins"] > "299":
        inventory['coins'] = inventory['coins'] - 300
        inventory['Fishing Rod'] = '1'
        print (inventory)
FishingRod ()`

Comment: Full code: inventory = {'coins':'750',}        def displayInventory(inventory):         print (inventory)           displayInventory(inventory)          def FishingRod ():               if inventory["coins"] > "299":             inventory['coins'] = inventory['coins'] - 300 
        inventory['Fishing Rod'] = '1'              print (inventory)           FishingRod ()

Comment: As I said, change the values to be ints. Why do you save the coins amount as a string? Change to `inventory = {'coins': 750}`

Comment: I changed inventory strings to  ints, and thank you, it did fix my problem, but I had to remove the code: `for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v + '   ' + k)` which would print out my inventory like this:`12   Arrows
42   Gold Coins` but now it prints out my inventory like this: `{'coins': 750}`. If I restore the code I had to remove, I get this error: `print(v + '   ' + k)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: Full working code: `inventory = {'coins':750,}
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print (inventory)    
displayInventory(inventory)
def FishingRod ():
    if inventory["coins"] > 299:
        inventory['coins'] = inventory['coins'] - 300
        inventory['Fishing Rod'] = '1'
        displayInventory(inventory)
FishingRod ()` need to add this code: `for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v + '   ' + k)` Please help me I would really appreciate it and again thanks for solving my main problem.

Comment: Don't print like that. The more common way is to use `format`: `"{} {}".format(v, k)` Or if you have Python >3.6 you can use f-strings: `f"{v} {k}"`

Comment: how do I use this code for a dictionary inventory? It gives me a invalid syntax, I am not familiar how to program with this.     `format "{} {}".format(v, k)`

Comment: `for k,v in inventory.items(): print("{} {}".format(v, k))`

Comment: Tomerikoo, thank you so much! You have really helped me out! I will update this thread tomorrow and rate you very good!

Comment: That is not necessary (and not possible haha). Simply for your own sake, for future questions, read about [ask] and importantly about how to provide a [mre]. You should distill your question to a specific problem and not a whole program. You will see that this will also help you to actually figure out what the real problem is and make it easier for you to search for a solution. Also, generally try to read docs and search online, for example I recommended you the `format` method. If you would google about it you would find many examples for how to use it. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: For dictionary inventories, such as `inventory = {'Coins' = '42', 'Loaf Of Bread' = '2',}`, make sure to change the values to ints: `'Coins' = 42, 'Loaf Of Bread' = 2`. If you are going for looks and want your inventory to look like this: `42 Gold Coins
1 Rope
6 Torches`, and not like this: `{'Coins' = 42, 'Loaf Of Bread' = 2}`, add this code into your inventory(recommend putting this into an inventory def():) `for k,v in inventory.items(): 
        print("{} {}".format(v, k))`